# Non-destructive Healing in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, hdr

I want to use the (Spot) Healing Brush Tool or the Clone Stamp Tool non-destructively in the following manner. Assuming, we have a Camera RAW Smart Object created from a camera's RAW file. We are able to change saturation, exposure and so on directly be open the Smart Object. Normally, I create a new layer and do healing by sampling all layers. Than, the healing is drawn on the new layer (the Smart Object is not modified). Now, imagine I change the saturation of the Smart Object. Obviously this makes the healing useless because the healing is not saturated. Is there any possibility to "remember" the healing process to apply it after modifying the Smart Object? Furthermore, think of modifying the tone mapping of a HDR image (16 Bit) – the healing also would be useless.

Comment: As an apologist justification on why why can't do this: if you change the underlying image, the results of healing can be very different. To get the same results you may need to apply the healing to a slightly different area, and Photoshop can't guess that.

Comment: Since this question is on-topic for Super User, you're welcome to leave it here. However, there is a [se] site specifically for photography, and its scope includes processing and touching up photos. If you would like a moderator to move your post to [photo.se], flag for moderator attention using the flag link below your post, and ask.